# PIG_HOME environment variable in a pig latin script

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to access the $PIG_HOME environment variable from within a pig latin script.

I want something like this (doesn't work):

```
register $PIG_HOME/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar
```

instead of hardcoding like this (works):

```
register /home/user/opt/pig-0.11.1/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing that comes to mind is just to call pig like:

```
pig -param PIG_HOME=$PIG_HOME myscript.pig
```

However, I recommend looking into [python wrappers](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/cont.html#embed-python). It may be overkill for just this,  but they just make everything so much easier. You also get to use python, which I always consider a plus.

Comment: thanks for that link. The python wrapper was exactly what I needed!